# Outlook365 Send email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

Hi every body I'm trying to make an app with the functionality to send email through Outlook365, I follow the instruction of this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#create-and-send-messages but not succeed ,

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail -- is my end point

Headers
Authorization -- Bearer (access token)
Content-Type --- application/json

Message to send(test)

```
{
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "test@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

Respond On Postman

```
403 Forbidden
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

I'm using Postman for this first, but I try too using MicrosoftGraph and OutlookClientService and nothing.

Comment: Have you checked your credentials and tried again?

Comment: How I check it?

Comment: You need to get app credentials, create your auth headers from them, and include them in your HTTP request. I think all the links are here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview

Comment: This link might be better if you're just starting out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: the last link show me how to make a request for get access token and get messages, I don't have problems with that , I can see the messages and attachment too, the problem is when i try to send messages

Comment: Got it!! Was the scopes, I have to define this scope https://outlook.office.com/mail.send when I request the access token